# Regenerate validation.pem for my organization

Tags: chef-infra

I'm using chef server 12 (on premises, open version) and I'd like to know what is the way to regenerate the organization validation key but not using the chef manage (GUI).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`knife client reregister`, just like any other client. The validation client isn't special other than having a few extra access control entries. That said, use of the validation key is discouraged these days. It's only needed for some specific auto-scaling scenarios.